# Sending a ICMPv6 Packet with VLAN while using Impacket

Tags: python, vlan, impacket, pcapy

Hey guys I am quite a bind I have this function

```
def send_ra_packet(self,source_link_layer, send_frequency,vlan_id = 0):
    ip = IP6.IP6()
    ip.set_source_address(self.get_source_address())
    ip.set_destination_address(self.get_target_address())
    ip.set_traffic_class(0)
    ip.set_flow_label(0)
    ip.set_hop_limit(64)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMPV6)
    payload = self.create_ra_message(source_link_layer)
    print send_frequency

    for i in range(0, send_frequency):
        icmp = ICMP6.ICMP6()
        icmp.set_byte(0, 134) # Put Type?
        icmp.set_byte(1, 00)  # Put Code?
        payloadObject = ImpactPacket.Data()
        payloadObject.set_data(payload)
        icmp.contains(payloadObject)
        # Have the IP packet contain the ICMP packet (along with its payload).
        ip.contains(icmp)
        ip.set_next_header(ip.child().get_ip_protocol_number())
        ip.set_payload_length(ip.child().get_size())

        eth = ImpactPacket.Ethernet()
        vlan = ImpactPacket.EthernetTag()
        vlan.set_vid(1)
        eth.push_tag(vlan)
        icmp.calculate_checksum()
        eth.contains(ip)
        print icmp.get_packet()

        # Send it to the target host.
        s.sendto(eth.get_packet(), (self.get_target_address(), 0))
        print "Success Sending Packet - %d " % (i)
```

A quick overview of the function will tell you that I am creating a RA Packet and sending it in my network, my problem here is that I can't seem to send an RA Packet with VLAN.

My additional code starting from `eth = ImpacketPacket.Ethernet()`
will tell you I created a Header that has a VLAN and made it as a parent of ip which has the instance IPV6.

My problem is that when ever I run the code the resulting packet that will be sent is Uknown (0)
which means that it is either corrupted or cannot be understand.

I am quite stuck with this problem for almost a week now and tried numerous ways to send it. I am not sure anymore what is the bug, if ever I send the packet with icmp instead of eth it works fine`

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ ?

Comment: I am hoping to use Impacket since the whole project is based on it